# Fill missing dates and back fill values for each group in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to fill missed `year`s say from `2015~2019` for each `city` and `bfill` the `value`s.

```
  city  year  value
0   bj  2017     15
1   bj  2019     17
2   sh  2015     23
3   sh  2016     24
4   sh  2019     16
```

How can I get the expected result like this? Thanks.

```
  city  year  value
0   bj  2015     15
1   bj  2016     15
2   bj  2017     15
3   bj  2018     17
4   bj  2019     17
5   sh  2015     23
6   sh  2016     24
7   sh  2017     16
8   sh  2018     16
9   sh  2019     16
```

I have tried with code below to create `city` and `year` pairs:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015', '2019', freq='YS').year
c = df['city'].unique()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([c, rng], names=['city','year'])
print(mux)
```

I get:

```
MultiIndex([('bj', 2015),
            ('bj', 2016),
            ('bj', 2017),
            ('bj', 2018),
            ('bj', 2019),
            ('sh', 2015),
            ('sh', 2016),
            ('sh', 2017),
            ('sh', 2018),
            ('sh', 2019)],
           names=['city', 'year'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex` in DaatFrame created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html) by first level `city`:

```
df = df.set_index(['city','year']).reindex(mux).groupby(level=0).bfill().reset_index()
print (df)
  city  year  value
0   bj  2015   15.0
1   bj  2016   15.0
2   bj  2017   15.0
3   bj  2018   17.0
4   bj  2019   17.0
5   sh  2015   23.0
6   sh  2016   24.0
7   sh  2017   16.0
8   sh  2018   16.0
9   sh  2019   16.0
```

Comment: you have missed to copy the creation of variable `mux`?

Comment: my bad. sorry :-)

Comment: Thank u. I should use `rng = pd.date_range('2015', '2019', freq='YS').year`, this is better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Going just from your original data without multi-index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': {0: 'bj', 1: 'bj', 2: 'sh', 3: 'sh', 4: 'sh'},
                   'year': {0: 2017, 1: 2019, 2: 2015, 3: 2016, 4: 2019},
                   'value': {0: 15, 1: 17, 2: 23, 3: 24, 4: 16}})

print (df.groupby("city").apply(lambda x: x.set_index("year")
       .reindex(range(min(df["year"]),max(df["year"]+1))).bfill())
       .drop("city",axis=1).reset_index())

"""
  city  year  value
0   bj  2015   15.0
1   bj  2016   15.0
2   bj  2017   15.0
3   bj  2018   17.0
4   bj  2019   17.0
5   sh  2015   23.0
6   sh  2016   24.0
7   sh  2017   16.0
8   sh  2018   16.0
9   sh  2019   16.0
"""
```

Comment: Thanks. Why need to use `drop("city",axis=1)`?

Comment: Because the column `city` will be duplicated and result in a `ValueError` since we use `apply` :)